# How to check html tag with Rspec

Tags: html, ruby, rspec

I'm learning from [this site](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec-adding_a_page). I tested the following with rspec, and it passed.

```
  describe "About page" do
    it "should have the content 'About Us'" do
      visit '/static_pages/about'
      expect(page).to have_content('About Us')
    end
  end
```

I changed `About Us` to `<h1>About Us</h1>` to check whether it works as I expected, but the test fails even when `about.html.erb` has the string `<h1>About Us</h1>`. Could you show me how I can use html tag expression in rspec file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you would like to check that the page has text 'About Us' in tag h1. You can use rich Capybara [functionality](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara).

For example you can use `within`

```
within('h1') do
  expect(page).to have_content('About Us')
end
```

There are another ways for example use css-selectors or xpath